# How to take the last character of string split using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to alert the last character of a string split, using innerHTML, but it's showing nothing in alert box.

this is my code

Html

```
<html> 
  <head>
  <title>JavaScript basic animation</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="myfunction_2.js"></script>
  </head> <body>
  <div id="target">w3resource </div>


<button onclick="shubham()">click</button>

  </body> 
  </html>
```

Function

```
function shubham() 
{
var x=document.getElementById('target').innerHTML;

var y=x.split('');

var z=y[0];

var m=y[9];

var n=y[1]


var last=y[y.length-1]

alert(last);


}
```

it works properly if I take var x as

```
var x='w3resource';
```

but i need to take x value as

```
var x=document.getElementById('target').innerHTML;
```

so what should i do for this???

Comment: You have a space in your #target element text. This is not a good way to get the last character of text by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML`.  `innerHTML` gets you the actual HTML markup, including the tag angled brackets (`<>`), whereas `textContent` will give you just the text.

```
var x=document.getElementById('target').textContent.trim();
```

Comment: @naresh Because as others have said, the last character is whitespace. You could always use `var x=document.getElementById('target').textContent.trim()` to remove the whitespace

Comment: Updated answer to include `trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code code exactly what it should do - it alerts a last character of #target element (which is a whitespace in your case).

If you changed `<div id="target">w3resource </div>` to `<div id="target">w3resource</div>` (removed the space at the end) the result would be 'e'.

If you want to find the very last text character you would have to use:

```js
function shubham() {
  // Element reference
  const element = document.getElementById('target');

  // Text without spaces at the beggining and the end
  const text = element.innerText.trim();
  
  // Get the last character
  const lastCharacter = text[text.length - 1];
  
  // Alert the last character
  alert(lastCharacter);
}
```

```html
<div id="target">w3resource </div>
<button onclick="shubham()">click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a space in the target div:

```
<div id="target">w3resource </div>
```

Hence the last character is a blank space, remove all the blank space and it should work, use the function below :

```
function shubham3() 
{
   var x=document.getElementById('target').innerHTML.replace(/ /g,'');

   var y=x.split('');

   var z=y[0];

   var m=y[9];

   var n=y[1]


   var last=y[y.length-1]

   alert(last);


 }
```